# TypeError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node' in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-statements, jsx

Inside of my render method I am calling a method which performs some conditional logic, based on API response data. I'm unclear how to resolve this error, considering I am not removing anything from the DOM. Here is my method

```
import numeral from 'numeral';
import moment from 'moment';

class SearchResultsListItem extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.isMaxQtyGreaterThanOneThousand=
    ::this.isMaxQtyGreaterThanOneThousand;
  }

 isMaxQtyGreaterThanOneThousand(qty){
   if(!!qty){
     if(qty%1000 === 0){
       return (numeral(qty).divide(1000).format('0,000') + 'M');
     }else{
       return numeral(qty);
     }
   }else{ return "-";}
 }


render() {
  const x = this.props.dataItem;

  return (
    <div className={`${s['quantity-block']}`}>
      {this.isMaxQtyGreaterThanOneThousand(x.MaxQuantity)}
    </div>
  )
}
```

I've looked at the following posted in order to resolve this error, but haven't had much luck finding anything specific to jsx or React:

[Javascript error: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43317676/javascript-error-uncaught-typeerror-failed-to-execute-removechild-on-node)

[Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37495059/failed-to-execute-removechild-on-node-parameter-1-is-not-of-type-node)

Answer (score 1):

The error is because in some cases you are returning a `numeral` object instead of a text string from your helper method.  This is confusing React.

You probably want

```
return numeral(qty).format('0,000');
```

instead of

```
return numeral(qty)
```

Comment: I performed my evaluation outside of my `render` method like so: 

const adjustedMaxQty = numeral(x.MaxQuantity).divide(1000).format('0,000') + 'M';

Then inside of my render method I perform the following logic:


              {x.MaxQuantity?
                ((x.MaxQuantity>1000)? adjustedMaxQty: x.MaxQuantity)
                :
                "-"
              }

This resolved my error.